# Countdown timer in Android game for points

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask, android-service, countdowntimer

What is the best way to implement countdown timer for points in android game, ex: the user loses all points & he will receive 5 points after 1 hour.
how to implement this taking into consideration that the app might be destroyed & the remaining time for the 5 points will be visible in the app while running!
note: the game is simple not using engine just android pure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the time "run" while user is not in the game, or not? If it does "run" in background too, just store the starting time of the game, and calculate everything from that (`duration = *now* - start_time;`).

In case the timer stops in background, store total duration with some reasonable accuracy (1s may be enough if bonuses change per-hour), and store session_start in onGameResume, and recalculate duration in onGameStop from `duration += *now* - session_start`.

Programmer hint: whenever working with "timestamps", use UTC time [for storage and calculations] (not user timezone, as it can change easily, if the user travels/etc). The timezone adjusted dates and times are "view formatting", done before displaying the value, not part of value storage.

Such simple implementation is easy to cheat by changing device time manually before running the game. In case it is somewhat more competitive challenge, you may consider to add some obfuscated guarding mechanisms, like storing which dates already happened and use them for some heuristic to detect manipulations (but be aware the device itself may easily go +-several minutes by jump in case it's RTC is very inaccurate, battery was depleted for longer time, or user is travelling into weird timezone (IIRC there are some with +-30min offset), and seasoned hacker will disable also your additional checks anyway, so don't spend too much effort on it, somebody will cheat it).